# Django allauth invalid token error not showing

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using allauth for authentication in my Django project.

In PasswordResetFromKeyView, I can't figure out why there is not error showing when the password reset token is invalid, for whatever reason.

Instead, the token is caught as invalid but the page simply reloads without any message to the user.

**allauth.account.views.PasswordResetFromKeyView**

```
class PasswordResetFromKeyView(AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView):
template_name = (
    "account/password_reset_from_key." + app_settings.TEMPLATE_EXTENSION)
form_class = ResetPasswordKeyForm
success_url = reverse_lazy("account_reset_password_from_key_done")

def get_form_class(self):
    return get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS,
                          'reset_password_from_key',
                          self.form_class)

def dispatch(self, request, uidb36, key, **kwargs):
    self.request = request
    self.key = key

    if self.key == INTERNAL_RESET_URL_KEY:
        self.key = self.request.session.get(INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_KEY, '')
        # (Ab)using forms here to be able to handle errors in XHR #890
        token_form = UserTokenForm(
            data={'uidb36': uidb36, 'key': self.key})
        if token_form.is_valid():
            self.reset_user = token_form.reset_user
            return super(PasswordResetFromKeyView, self).dispatch(request,
                                                                  uidb36,
                                                                  self.key,
                                                                  **kwargs)
    else:
        token_form = UserTokenForm(
            data={'uidb36': uidb36, 'key': self.key})
        if token_form.is_valid():
            # Store the key in the session and redirect to the
            # password reset form at a URL without the key. That
            # avoids the possibility of leaking the key in the
            # HTTP Referer header.
            self.request.session[INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_KEY] = self.key
            redirect_url = self.request.path.replace(
                self.key, INTERNAL_RESET_URL_KEY)
            return redirect(redirect_url)

    self.reset_user = None
    response = self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(token_fail=True)
    )
    return _ajax_response(self.request, response, form=token_form)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ret = super(PasswordResetFromKeyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ret['action_url'] = reverse(
        'account_reset_password_from_key',
        kwargs={'uidb36': self.kwargs['uidb36'],
                'key': self.kwargs['key']})
    return ret
```

**View**

```
class PasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetFromKeyView):
form_class = PasswordResetConfirmForm
template_name = 'users/password_reset_confirm.html'

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('account_login')
```

**Template**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Confirm New Password</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save password</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you override the template? If the form is invalid, the context is passed `token_fail` as `True`, which in the template would render the message for token invalid.

Comment: @dirkgroten I did override the template and I'm subclassing the view (edited original post to show how).

Comment: In your template, you should have a `{% if token_fail %} Error message {% else %} <your form> {% endif %}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The allauth view uses the template "account/password_reset_from_key.html". You should check that, because it contains an if/else statement to display an error if the token is invalid:

```
<h1>{% if token_fail %}{% trans "Bad Token" %}{% else %}{% trans "Change Password" %}{% endif %}</h1>

{% if token_fail %}
    Some error message
{% else %}
    <form> ... </form>
{% endif %}
```

So when you override the template, just make sure you do something in case `token_fail` is `True`.